# set tag property of control as a string in ios 5.0

Tags: iphone, ios5, tags

I want to perform changes in the code which was developed using iOS 3.0, so that it can run on iOS 5.0.

But the problem is this , the `tag` property of any control in iphone not taking the `NSString` value in iOS 5.0, while in iOS 3.0  there is no issue related to assign `tag` as a `NSString`.

I am getting this warning in iOS 5.0:

```
lview.tag=@"lblPatientDetail";

"incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to integer'(aka 'int') from NSString"
```

This warning is present all over the project which is causing high number of issues.

So is there a way where we can assign `NSString` as a `tag` value in iOS 5.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NSDictionary instead if you want to recognize an object by string. I will provide the example below on how to use NSDictionary.

```
NSDictionary *dictionary;
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"key1", @"key2", @"key3", nil];

NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"How", @"are", @"you", nil];

dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];

for (id key in dictionary) {

    NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", key, [dictionary objectForKey:key]);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The UIView [tag](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) property is an NSInteger so you cannot assign a string value to it. The immediate solution to your problem is to use integer values for the tag, not strings.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible way of doing this, if you specifically looking for strings(with any of this way you actually have to use int) -

1. Create a enum for these string values, then use enum.
2. You can convert string to int, by using intValue method.

Answer (score 0):

Add micro to store NSInteger and The use micro as string.